# Custom CSS code in SharePoint Online site not showing for all users

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site created in SharePoint Online that I have applied a custom css file through the Master Page - Alternate CSS. The css file is saved in the Style Library, it is checked in and published as a major version. I am using the default master page and it is also checked in. As an admin I can see the CSS changes on the site but as another user that has read access I cannot see the CSS changes. The read only users can see the top level site. I have checked the site features at site collection and site and all publishing features are active. What setting could I be missing that would cause this CSS not to show? The CSS changes are specifically to hide some buttons on the app launcher just for this site.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just checking... you mentioned you had your master page checked in,  but you didn't mention that you had it published.  i'm assuming you do, but since you didn't mention it, it's the best place to start.   Second thing i would do,  is confirm the access the users have to the CSS file. If everything is published,  then it's most likely a permissions issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

CSS on Master page page will be shown to all authenticated users if CSS(style library) and master page both are checked in and published as major version.
also try removing cache and so proper revision of CSS and JS file before deployment.
also check console of browser for non accessible file :)